# mysql SELECT where FIELD alphanumerically match with WHERE IN, remove special characters while matching

Tags: mysql

Table : orders

```
+---------------+--------+
| order_number  | amount |
+---------------+--------+
| ASD-12/53-DF  |    152 |
| FVB1256DF     |    110 |
| FCB/150/KL    |     95 |
+---------------+--------+
```

Original Query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders where order_number IN ('ASD1253DF','FVB1256DF','FCB150KL');
```

This should fetch records by removing special characters from table field.

Comment: 'Desired query'? That's original.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using builtin MySQL functions, we could "remove" occurrences of a character using the `REPLACE()` function, but it would be a separate function call for each character.

Given the sample data, looks like there are only two characters that need to be removed, the slash and the dash characters.

As a demonstration, consider:

```
 SELECT t.order_number
      , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( t.order_number ,'/',''),'-',''),' ','') AS rep_order_number
   FROM ( SELECT 'ASD-12/53-DF' AS order_number
          UNION ALL SELECT 'FVB 1256DF'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'FCB/150/KL'
        ) t
```

returns:

```
order_number  rep_order_number
------------  ----------------
ASD-12/53-DF  ASD1253DF
FVB 1256DF    FVB1256DF
FCB/150/KL    FCB150KL
```

---

If we're going to use an expression like that (with a column wrapped in REPLACE functions), that will require the expression to evaluated on every value of the column; it can't make use of an index.

```
 WHERE expr IN ('fee','fi','fo','fum')
```

---

For performance, we would prefer to materialize that expression as a column (or derived column) in the table, so we can make use of an index.

---

In terms of removing special characters, the example expression only removes the specified characters. If an order number were to contain an asterisk character, that would not be removed.

We need to consider the question:  do we want to blacklist the characters we want to exclude, or do we want to whitelist the characters we want to include.

For whitelisting allowed characters, consider a user defined function. Here's an example that allows digits 0 thru 9, upper and lower case letters, and underscore character:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `udf_strip_alphanum`(as_arg VARCHAR(2000)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(2000) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
-- #############################################################################
-- Purpose: return string contains only specified set of characters
-- other characters removed
-- #############################################################################
   DECLARE ls_char CHAR(1)        DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE ls_ret  VARCHAR(2000)  DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE _i      INT            DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE _len    INT            DEFAULT 0;
   SET _len := CHAR_LENGTH(as_arg);
   -- early exit for zero length or null
   IF _len IS NULL OR _len = 0 THEN
      RETURN as_arg;
   END IF;
   -- safety net for input string over 2000 character limit:
   IF _len > 2000 THEN
      SET _len := 2000;
   END IF;
   WHILE _i < _len DO
      SET _i := _i + 1;
      SET ls_char := SUBSTRING(as_arg,_i,1);
      IF INSTR('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_',ls_char) THEN
         SET ls_ret := CONCAT(ls_ret,ls_char);
      END IF;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN ls_ret;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The list of allowed characters is easy to modify.

```
 SELECT t.order_number
      , udf_strip_alphanum( t.order_number )
   FROM ( SELECT 'ASD-12/53-DF' AS order_number
          UNION ALL SELECT 'FVB 1256DF'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'FCB/150/KL'
        ) t
```